# PHP referencing array element (&$array['element']) creates element

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference

I have a function that checks if a variable is exists.

```
function variable( &$var, $default = NULL )
{
    if( (!isset($var) && !is_array($var)) || empty($var) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    elseif( is_array($var) && count($var) <= 0 )
    {
        return FALSE;       
    }
    else
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

My problem is, that this function creates an array when I pass an array element reference like $array['element'] the array $array and the index 'element' is created even if it did not exists before.

What the function is supposed to do is having something like echo variable($var); which does no produce an error even if $var is not defined.

Is there a way to delete this again or even better not let the function create the array?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is very vague. Can you post the full code you are using? :)

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php

array_key_exists is the "key", no pun intended :-)

like so:

```
if (array_key_exists('element', $array)({
    // do the fan dango
}
```

Answer (score -4):

To delete, you can use unset($array['element']); or unset($array); depending on your goal. 
For making sure the array turns into a string, just use implode("",$array);

Comment: I'm assuming the whole point of this question is to find out how to check if the element exists without the side-effect of it being created.